# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError setBackgroundResource

Tags: java, android, drawable, out-of-memory, setbackground

I have different buttons for loading images in imageview.
when the user clicks the first button  10 images are loaded when the user clicks the second button load more images 10,  and the other 10 images are not displayed, but when he click the third button to load the other 10 pictures I I get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. how can I get rid of this problem? I have read many posts here, and I have tried various methods such as the use of bitmap and then recycle the bitmap, but I give all the same error. I do not want the pictures are deleted when the user clicks on the button because they have to be re-used several times. is there any way to push aside the images in the memory? or reset memory cache? help me thanks in advance. this code works in Android versions 2.3.3, but in versions 4.1 crashes
 this is the code:

```
ImageView  
    imageView1n,imageView2n,imageView3n,imageView4n,imageView5n,imageView6n,imageView7n,imageView8n,imageView9n,imageView10n,
    imageView1b,imageView2b,imageView3b,imageView4b,imageView5b,imageView6b,imageView7b,imageView8b,imageView9b,imageView10b,
imageView1l,imageView2l,imageView3l,imageView4l,imageView5l,imageView6l,imageView7l,imageView8l,imageView9l,imageView10l;






protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        imageView1n=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1n);

        imageView2n=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2n);

        imageView3n=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3n);

        imageView4n=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4n);

        imageView5n=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5n);

        imageView6n=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6n);

        imageView7n=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView7n);

        imageView8n=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView8n);

        imageView9n=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView9n);

        imageView10n=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView10n);

imageView1b=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1b);

        imageView2b=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2b);

        imageView3b=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3b);

        imageView4b=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4b);

        imageView5b=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5b);

        imageView6b=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6b);

        imageView7b=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView7b);

        imageView8b=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView8b);

        imageView9b=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView9b);

        imageView10b=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView10b);


imageView1l=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1l);

        imageView2l=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2l);

        imageView3l=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3l);

        imageView4l=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4l);

        imageView5l=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5l);

        imageView6l=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6l);

        imageView7l=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView7l);

        imageView8l=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView8l);

        imageView9l=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView9l);

        imageView10l=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView10l);    






 Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Bopenbx);
                       button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
                          @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                        @Override
                           public void onClick(View arg1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                             MediaPlayer playSuccess = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.button_opengohan1);


                            playSuccess.start();
                            playSuccess.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer playSuccess) {
                                    playSuccess.reset();
                                }
                            });






                   Button button1b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Bopenbx);
                   button1b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gohan_open1);
                   Button button2b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Bopennx);
                   button2b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.vegeta_open0);
                   Button button3b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Bopenlx);
                   button3b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goku_open0);




 imageView1b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gohan_1);
                      imageView2b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gohan_2);
                      imageView3b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gohan_3);
                      imageView4b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gohan_4);
                      imageView5b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gohan_5);
                      imageView6b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gohan_6);
                      imageView7b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gohan_7);
                      imageView8b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gohan_8);
                      imageView9b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gohan_9);
                      imageView10b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gohan_10);




imageView1b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  imageView2b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  imageView3b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  imageView4b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  imageView5b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  imageView6b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  imageView7b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  imageView8b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  imageView9b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  imageView10b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


imageView1n.setImageDrawable(null);
                imageView2n.setImageDrawable(null);
                imageView3n.setImageDrawable(null);
                imageView4n.setImageDrawable(null);
                imageView5n.setImageDrawable(null);
                imageView6n.setImageDrawable(null);
                imageView7n.setImageDrawable(null);
                imageView8n.setImageDrawable(null);
                imageView9n.setImageDrawable(null);
                imageView10n.setImageDrawable(null);
                imageView1l.setImageDrawable(null);
                imageView2l.setImageDrawable(null);
                imageView3l.setImageDrawable(null);
                imageView4l.setImageDrawable(null);
                imageView5l.setImageDrawable(null);
                imageView6l.setImageDrawable(null);
                imageView7l.setImageDrawable(null);
                imageView8l.setImageDrawable(null);
                imageView9l.setImageDrawable(null);
                imageView10l.setImageDrawable(null);
imageView1l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageView2l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageView3l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageView4l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageView5l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageView6l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageView7l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageView8l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageView9l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageView10l.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                     imageView1n.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageView2n.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageView3n.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageView4n.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageView5n.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageView6n.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageView7n.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageView8n.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageView9n.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageView10n.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}







                       });




Button button2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Bopenlx);
                       button2.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
                          @Override
                           public void onClick(View arg2) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                             MediaPlayer playSuccess = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.button_opengoku1);


                            playSuccess.start();
                            playSuccess.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer playSuccess) {
                                    playSuccess.reset();
                                }
                            });        










                              Button button1l = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Bopenbx);
                              button1l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gohan_open0);
                              Button button2l = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Bopennx);
                              button2l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.vegeta_open0);
                              Button button3l = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Bopenlx);
                              button3l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goku_open1);



 imageView1l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goku_1);
                            imageView2l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goku_2);
                            imageView3l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goku_3);
                            imageView4l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goku_4);
                            imageView5l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goku_5);
                            imageView6l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goku_6);
                            imageView7l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goku_7);
                            imageView8l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goku_8);
                            imageView9l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goku_9);
                            imageView10l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goku_10);


imageView1l.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                imageView2l.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                imageView3l.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                imageView4l.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                imageView5l.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                imageView6l.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                imageView7l.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                imageView8l.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                imageView9l.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                imageView10l.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


imageView1b.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView2b.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView3b.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView4b.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView5b.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView6b.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView7b.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView8b.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView9b.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView10b.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView1n.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView2n.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView3n.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView4n.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView5n.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView6n.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView7n.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView8n.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView9n.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView10n.setImageDrawable(null);

 imageView1b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              imageView2b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              imageView3b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              imageView4b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              imageView5b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              imageView6b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              imageView7b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              imageView8b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              imageView9b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              imageView10b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              imageView1n.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              imageView2n.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              imageView3n.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              imageView4n.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              imageView5n.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              imageView6n.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              imageView7n.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              imageView8n.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              imageView9n.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              imageView10n.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }    



                       });



 Button button3=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Bopennx);
                       button3.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
                          @Override
                           public void onClick(View arg3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                             MediaPlayer playSuccess = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.button_openvegeta1);


                            playSuccess.start();
                            playSuccess.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer playSuccess) {
                                    playSuccess.reset();
                                }
                            });







                            Button button1n = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Bopenbx);
                            button1n.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gohan_open0);
                            Button button2n = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Bopennx);
                            button2n.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.vegeta_open1);
                            Button button3n = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Bopenlx);
                            button3n.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goku_open0);





imageView1n.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.vegeta_1);
                            imageView2n.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.vegeta_2);
                            imageView3n.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.vegeta_3);
                            imageView4n.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.vegeta_4);
                            imageView5n.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.vegeta_5);
                            imageView6n.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.vegeta_6);
                            imageView7n.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.vegeta_7);
                            imageView8n.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.vegeta_8);
                            imageView9n.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.vegeta_9);
                            imageView10n.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.vegeta_10);







                            imageView1n.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            imageView2n.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            imageView3n.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            imageView4n.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            imageView5n.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            imageView6n.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            imageView7n.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            imageView8n.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            imageView9n.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            imageView10n.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



imageView1b.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView2b.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView3b.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView4b.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView5b.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView6b.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView7b.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView8b.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView9b.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView10b.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView1l.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView2l.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView3l.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView4l.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView5l.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView6l.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView7l.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView8l.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView9l.setImageDrawable(null);
                            imageView10l.setImageDrawable(null);



                                imageView1b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                imageView2b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                imageView3b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                imageView4b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                imageView5b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                imageView6b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                imageView7b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                imageView8b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                imageView9b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                imageView10b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                imageView1l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                imageView2l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                imageView3l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                imageView4l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                imageView5l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                imageView6l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                imageView7l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                imageView8l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                imageView9l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                imageView10l.setVisibility(View.GONE);



       }    


                       });
```

Comment: check this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html and this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: thanks but the recycle method is used when it is no longer necessary to display the resource, I want that can be reused at a later time

Comment: and what is the problem in recycling the bitmap?

Comment: that when I call the button 1 and 10 visualize the images, I have to recycle them in the button 2, and if I click on button 1 again I get the same error

Comment: if you want I can post my code to use the bitmap to see if there is something wrong

Answer (score -1):

This will solve your problem: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

And to release extra memory call garbage collector by: System.gc();